# Moq - mocking a complex repository method - list object not being returned

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

I am using Entity Framework and have a generic repository method that allows me to query a `DbSet` and also include navigation properties.  I am trying to write a unit test for some code that uses this chunk of code and I need to mock it for a unit test.  I am using Moq.

Here is the repository method - it is a method that allows me to query using an expression and also including the relevant navigation properties that I want.  I saw this pattern in Julie Lerman's EF in the Enterprise course on Pluralsight.

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> FindByInclude(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate,
                                            params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    var query = GetAllIncluding(includeProperties);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> results = query.Where(predicate).ToList();
    return results;
}

private IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> queryable = DbSet.AsNoTracking();

    return includeProperties.Aggregate
      (queryable, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
}
```

Here is an example of how I am calling using this method in my code ( I am just showing the relevant part of the method):

```
public ApiResult DeleteLocation(int id)
{
    var location = _locationRepository
        .FindByInclude(l => l.Id == id, l => l.LocationRegions, l => l.Pools)
        .Single();
```

So this query would bring back a Single `Location` entity by the id I have passed in and the related `LocationRooms` and `Staff` collections.

How do I set up Moq for the `FindByInclude` method? Here is what I have for my unit test mock setup:

```
var mockLocationRepository = new Mock<ILocationRepository>();
var location = new Location {Id = 1,Name = "LocationName", LocationRooms = new List<LocationRoom>(), Staff = new List<Staff>()};
mockLocationRepository.Setup(r => r.FindByInclude(l => l.Id == It.IsAny<int>(), l => l.LocationRooms, l => l.Staff))
            .Returns(() => new List<Location> { location });
```

From the Moq setup code shown here - I think I should be getting back a list of 1 location - the location object I specified with Id of 1.  However when I run my unit test and hit this code - the setup method for `FindByInclude` returns an empty list.  And therefore when the code in the `DeleteLocation` method gets hit and the Single() method is called I am getting an error that the "element contains no sequence".

I think the problem is I have something wrong with the syntax with the Moq Setup for the `FindByInclude` method but not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment so adding as an answer

it is the expressions. Try a more general expression setup first and see if it works.

```
var location = new Location {
    Id = 1,
    Name = "LocationName", 
    LocationRooms = new List<LocationRoom>(), 
    Staff = new List<Staff>()
};
mockLocationRepository
    .Setup(m => m.FindByInclude(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[]>())
    .Returns(() => new List<Location> { location });
```

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to @Nkosi's answer, how about you don't use Moq but implement yourself a stub implementation of `ILocationRepository`? The idea behind that is that if mocking becomes hard to do, maybe you shouldn't do it?

```cs
public class StubLocationRepository : ILocationRepository
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Location> _findByInclude;

    public StubLocationRepository(IEnumerable<Location> findByInclude)
    {
        _findByInclude = findByInclude;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Location> FindByInclude(
        Expression<Func<Location, bool>> predicate,
        params Expression<Func<Location, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        return _findByInclude;
    }
}
```

That's simplistic because it assumes you only have one method. If you have a lot and don't want to pass constant values for each of them, you could have the `ctor` of the stub take optional parameters so you only stub the desired methods.

Also, since `ILocationRepository` most likely inherits from a generic interface, you could have a generic stub implementation that you subclass to build specific stubs - i.e to implement the methods that `ILocationRepository` defines.